# Texture on hair cards looks zig zag

Tags: texturing, uv

I am trying to texture hair cards,  I UV unwrapped by multiple methods ( unwrap and then follow active quad /or reset UV and follow active quad) but when I put the texture on the card it is zig-zag, is it because I am trying to use a tear shape card with a rectangular UV? I`ve seen people doing this but get smooth textures, I am modeling in blender and texturing in substance.

first time trying hair cards method so the answer may be obvious but i just couldn't find the problem.

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: have  you  tried  the texture in blender?

Comment: @Bruk yes, i tried in blender, same problem, added the prtsc from blender too

Comment: You can lower this kind of effect by adding vertical loop cuts (vertical relatively to your pictures above). Or redo the UV map...

Comment: The problem seems like the uv map. Scale down  the  uv at the tips with proportional editing and widen at the middle.

Comment: @lemon yes it solved a bit but after i added 3 more loops i gave up because it still looked giggly , and i didn't want to make it more poly heavy so i gave up on that method and tried another that works now but i have to re-do the hair

Comment: @AndreeaHoroiu, in that case maybe, redo UV unwrap and adapt its width to your texture. And eventually add loop cuts as said before.

Comment: if i do that the texture will be just straight down, and the purpose of straight uv unwrap was that the texture would take the shape of the hair

Comment: well yes... so add vertical loop cuts... try to uv unwrap from view eventually (experimental things matters rarely general recipe)

Comment: if the final uv is shaped like the tear-like shape and not a rectangle, the hair will have straight lines instead of hair that follows the card ( getting clumped at the end) , adding more than 6 vertical loopcuts per card is working (not perfect but kinda working) but not worth it cuz id have way too many polygons in the end and i make the model for a  game, the question remains but i solved my problem by using particle hair and baking my own texture shapes and then applying them to the tear-shaped uv, so i had to re-do the whole hair but at least i know it looks like it needs to

Comment: The zig zag are due to stretched mesh part compared to the UV (non proportional width). You could bake it from a higher poly. And so avoid the 6+ additional vertices.